# How to get the original document from the index

Tags: lucene, couchdb, cloudant

I want to index every fields from a set of documents, and then retrieve the documents when one of the fields match the query.

Here an example of documents:

```
{
    "_id": "1234567890",
    "lname": "last",
    "name": "name",
    "mpc": {
        "id": "000000",
        "name": "name"
    },
    "type": "agent",
    …
},
{
    "_id": "1234567891",
    "lname": "last",
    "name": "name",
    "mpc": {
        "id": "000001",
        "name": "name"
    },
    "type": "agent",
    …
}
```

Starting form the code taken from here: https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene#example-index-functions, I understand why I get the result, but I did not found how to retrieve the original documents, and not the aggregates.

```
{
  "_id": "_design/search",
  "fulltext": {
    "all": {
      "index": "function(doc) { var ret = new Document(); function idx(obj) { for (var key in obj) { switch (typeof obj[key]) { case 'object': idx(obj[key]); break; case 'function': break; default: ret.add(obj[key], {\"store\": \"yes\"}); break; } } }; idx(doc); return ret;}"
    }
  }
}
```

So, when I try to query `http://localhost:5985/local/database/_design/search/all?q=name`, I get all the data flatten, but not the original document hierarchy.

Is there any built-in method that allow to get what I want?

Comment: What if you add ?include_docs=true

Comment: @AlexisCôté, as simple as that…  `http://localhost:5985/local/database/_design/search/all?include_docs=true&q=name`. Can you provide your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Search parameters usable here: https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene#search-parameters

You can simply add to your query the following parameter: `?include_docs=true`